# Mobile Value Added Services with SMS

Tags: sms, sms-gateway

I'm new comer in mobile value added service field. I searched & read other company's presentation for mobile value added service with sms platform. But I can't find the right way. I don't know where to start, which platform or server should use for it. I will explain road map first. I will provide content with sms. If you wanna get the contents from me, you need to subscribe first. Then, I will sent contents to all subscribed numbers daily. Then, I will charge for content daily. Please help me which platform or server should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a short code for that, in which country are you in?

Comment: I live in Myanmar. Yes I want to know more about it detail.

Comment: You can find an aggregator in your country that offers short code and at the same time allow revenue sharing, next you develop a platform that allows people subscribe for the content and its deducted maybe per message sent out by your system.